# Deserialize JSON file into Java object

Tags: java, json, deserialization

For example, I have a JSON file named simple.json which has the below code.

```json
[
  { "name" : "David", "age" : 45 },
  { "name" : "Norma", "age" : 44 }
]
```

and a class name Record.java

```java
public class Record{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   // corresponding constructor and getters functions

}
```

How do I de-serialize simple.json file into a list of record objects?

Maybe the list looks somewhat like `ArrayList<Record> recordList;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ObjectMapper` for this:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String jsonRecordArray =
        "[{ \"name\" : \"David\", \"age\" : 45 },\n" +
        " { \"name\" : \"Norma\", \"age\" : 44 }\n" +
        "]";
List<Record> listRecord = objectMapper.readValue(jsonRecordArray, new TypeReference<>() {
});
```

In maven the relevant dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Remember to handle `JsonProcessingException`, for example by adding it to the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the answer from jwpol is correct and could be used as a solution. Just a bit of additional clarifications: The library that @jwpol suggests is called JSON-Jackson or also known as faster XML. Here is the main [site](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for it and there are many others. This library is de-facto is JSON standard (used by default in Spring Boot). One popular alternative would be Gson - a Google implementation of JSON library. Here are 2 sites to  read about it: https://github.com/google/gson, https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide.

Also, for simplistic use where you just need simple serialization/de-serialization capabilities I wrote my own simple feature that is a thin wrapper over Jackson Json library that gives you simplified use without directly importing Jackson library and configuring it. With my feature your code could look like

```
    String jsonRecordArray =
            "[{ \"name\" : \"David\", \"age\" : 45 },\n" +
            " { \"name\" : \"Norma\", \"age\" : 44 }\n" +
            "]";
List<Record> listRecord;
    try {
      listRecord = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonRecordArray, List.class);
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
    ...
    }
```

BTW, in jwpol exaple exception handling is missing.

If you want to use my feature you need to import MgntUtils open source library written by me. You can get Maven artifacts [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and or get it on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc). Here is Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class

Comment: @Michael good point. Added to the answer.

Comment: @jwpol you are welcome, Debayan I am happy you resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

The below code served my purpose.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader("PATH_OF_THE_JSON_FILE");
Record[] recordList = gson.fromJson(reader, Record[].class);

for(Record record : recordList){
// Here I could access name and age of each
// record by record.getName() and record.getAge()
 }
```